# document.write not working in ie but working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, internet-explorer, google-chrome-extension

Im trying to fetch the html markup from a response and trying to override with current page to do some form submissions.

When i use document.write in chrome.. its fetching and overriding current html markup.
But IE is showing  blank screen, looks like document.write is not supported by IE.

```
 fetch('http://www.mocky.io/v2/5b2948502f00005b00f56127')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
  document.write(myJson)
   })
```

Could you please provide me a fix or a polyfill to be installed in our react application

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` in asynchronous callbacks.  By the time the AJAX call completes, the DOM will have been completed. Then calling `document.write()` will clear the DOM.

Comment: Are you using a fetch polyfill for Internet Explorer? (https://github.com/github/fetch).

Comment: document.write can overwrite entire page, not recommend to use